# Tool for automatic start from standby / sleep mode at a given time

Tags: windows, boot, standby

Is there a Windows-tool that is able to automatically revive the computer from standby / sleep mode at a given time?

Answer (score 1):

> Tool for automatic start from standby
>   / sleep mode at a given time

**[WakeupOnStandBy](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/download.php?what=WOSB)** will do this for you:

- **Can restore almost every Windows-based operating system from a Stand-by mode** (and some from hibernation) that support ACPI (Advanced Configuration and Power Interface) (For support check computer's BIOS as well as Control Panel -> Power Options);
- Can run a file or **open a web page at a predetermined time after a wake-up event**, during normal operation, or before performing power operation;
- Can send system back to Stand-by mode (hibernate it, shut it down, or log off user) after a certain time interval;
- Can detect if Stand-by mode (or hibernation) is supported by your system;
- Can turn the monitor on and hold off screen-saver during the waiting time;
- Can repair local area network and high-speed Internet connection upon waking up from a suspended state;
- Can send system into Stand-by mode or hibernate it with more options than available through Operating System;
- Can be incorporated into an in-car (entertainment) PC system to speed up booting time & save battery [more here];
- Can be run from the Windows Command Line without user interaction;
- Can be saved as a batch file for later use.

Comment: Do you know of an alternative that works for Windows 7? That one does not, at least not on my Dell Inspiron 9400.

Comment: @Jonas Elfström - i think not Windows 7 is the problem but rather the ACPI settings/capabilities of your Dell.

Comment: It worked after I switched on `Allow wake timers` in Advanced power settings. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas Elfström - you're welcome.

Comment: It worked last night and then I set it to start at 06:15 this morning but it had not. I started it manually and WSOB wasn't even running anymore. Does not seem to be very stable.

Answer (score 0):

I use a scheduled task, with the wake from stand by option checked.

**Edit:**

[image: Scheduled Task Options]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you do that ?